# What's the job title for temporary position when the real one is not in the office?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mr.A is the CEO of the company. Mr. B will be in charge when Mr. A is away for vacation, business trip, or etc. Is there a word or prefix to call Mr. B, for example, temporary CEO, acting CEO?

Comment: It seems form the answers that there is some confusion: do you mean a title for the person _that **is** handling someone's responsibilities_, or the person that _**will** handle someone's responsibilities_?

Comment: Acting seems appropriate. Mr. B will be acting/acting as CEO while Mr. A is away. Please direct appropriate queries to Mr. B.

Comment: Please check the link "About single word requests" and go through the list of questions at the bottom. When you add the additional information that's missing, we can see about re-opening this question.

Comment: @KitFox I reviewed those questions: 1) Does the question describe exactly in what context you want to use a single word? Yes, I explained the context and situation as clear as I can. 2) Does the question specify the criteria for which the suggested word will be accepted? Yes, I stated that I want a word or words that can refer to that job. 3) Does the question list which words you didn't like? No, it doesn't because I don't know which word is the right one. 4) Does the question show that you searched for a suitable word before asking the question? Yes, it does because I gave 2 example words.

Comment: Please suggest me if there is anything I need to improve to reopen the question.

Comment: @anonymous: to re-open the question, please clarify whether you want a title the person has *during the period the CEO is absent*, or a title for the person has *all the time*, whether or not the CEO is out (such title indicating he's the boss' understudy, informing everyone he will take over for the boss *if* the boss has to be absent at any time).

Answer (score 17):

I would use "***acting*** CEO", or in a very formal or serious situation (grave illness, maybe): "CEO ***pro tem***" (short for *pro tempore*, i.e. for the time being).

---

If you're looking for a word which can describe the person's *role* (not *title*) as a backup to the boss, whether or not the boss is currently absent, then as @Jaydles suggested in the comments, you can say "he is ***on standby***"; alternatively you could say exactly ***backup*** or the more formal ***understudy*** (typically reserved for acting/theatre).

For example: "The boss' wife is going to give birth any day now, so he's got Sam *on standby* for him" (or just "Sam *is on* standby"), or the boss could say "Bob's *my backup* in case I have to leave early" or "Umberto is *understudying me* [or *is my understudy*]".

Comment: _Acting_ is only applicable in the actual absence of the original. You don't apply the title to someone just _in case_. It is not uncommon though that a vice-president is acting president when needed, or a deputy-CEO is acting CEO when the latter is absent.

Comment: Given the phrasing of the question "a *temporary* position *when* the real one *is not* in office" and the example "*temporary* CEO", I'm pretty sure @anonymous wants the title of the person who *is currently* (albeit temporarily) handling the CEO's responsibilities. This is in contrast to a permanent title, like vice-president, which as I said below, is a role unto itself.

Comment: Ok, it seems I made the mistake of reading the _question_ instead of just the title. "Mr. B will be in charge when Mr. A is away[..] " doesn't seem to indicate that Mr.A **is** away at this moment. But I guess the voters have decided what the OP wanted - in his absence :)

Comment: +1 In big companies in the US, "acting" is by far the most commonly used, but as oerkelens points out, it's not applied to a person on "standby" unless you're talking about when they'll actually be called up. ("If Mr. A is away and unreachable, Mr. B will serve as acting CEO.")

Comment: I like "standby"; if you don't mind, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: "standby" is the best answer.  (Why would you not add it to your answer, Dan?!  heh)

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion for temporary CEO is **Interim CEO**

Definition:

> A person appointed by a company's board of directors to assume the
>   role of chief executive officer during a time of transition or as the
>   result of the sudden departure of the company's previous CEO. These
>   CEOs are tagged with the "interim" tag due to the fact that they have
>   not officially been given the title of full-time CEO. Like many
>   industry leaders, interim CEOs are often called upon to "steady the
>   ship" in periods of great turmoil.

**[Source](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/interim-ceo.asp)**

Comment: That doesn't fit the "vacation" or "business trip" part of the question. OP asks for someone to stand in for a person when they are temporarily away. An interim is appointed in between (that is what it means!) two people normally holding the position, and is often, as your source says, a measure in a **crisis** situation.

Comment: this is wrong.  he's looking for the word to describe the person "all the time" while "waiting" to take over when the main guy is missing

Answer (score 1):

You could, especially in British English, refer to such a person as a **locum**, short for *locum tenens*, "one holding a place".

> NOUN
>
> (British) A person who stands in temporarily for someone else of the
>   same profession, especially a cleric or doctor.

[Source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/locum)

Comment: This is actually in common use in British English; you could reasonably expect a doctor's receptionist to say "I'm sorry, but Dr Jones is on holiday. Would you be willing to see his locum instead?"

Comment: A AmE receptionist would more likely say "his *stand-in*" or "*substitute"* (we have *substitute teachers* here), but that has a whiff of decreased standards, like an imitation Rolex (sure, maybe, but I want the real thing). I imagine that doesn't apply to *locum* in BrE? In any case, it's a cool word.

Comment: I would indeed not consider a "locum" to be inferior. I suppose there may be a slight hint of *junior* (since a senior doctor is likely to be fixed to a partnership of their own), but I'm mostly hypothesising there.

Comment: it's an interesting point whether you can call someone a locum if they are "waiting to" fill a temp role, or, if you can only call them a locum while they "are filling" a temp role!  I don't know.  Great thinking though

Comment: @JoeBlow - I believe you would not generally refer to a permanent standby as a "locum"; only someone actually filling in at the moment.

Comment: I see.  You know, I think the OP is looking for that word describing someone who, "is on standby".

Comment: I *think* you are correct. However, I'm inclined to let my answer stand as a) the question is not 100% clear; and b) in any case my answer is at least closely related.

Comment: This reminded me of a *lieutenant* — the origin is *lieu* + *tenere*, which means someone who *holds* the *lieu* (place) of their superior